# exclamation points on facebook

Tags: facebook, hebrew

i want to say something in hebrew on facebook but it wont let me put an exclamation point after it :(  it always goes automatically to the front of the sentence.  if i dont fix it someone will think i'm not excited about their birthday!! help!!

Comment: Try asking on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Isnt hebrew written from right to left ? I can assume you are not working with code. So the correct thing to do is ask Mark Zukerberg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the exclamation point first and then your sentence. this problem occurs in all websites (even here) and only on facebook. its a RTL issue.